# Why getting Ionic Error to Build? - Error 65

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cocoapods

When build my ionic 4 project I getting this error:

error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-dlxqvfatclxsixazxpmwbqvzqpta/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myproject.build/Release-iphonesimulator/myproject.build/Script-95C8104D52AAF5838850DC1B.sh
(1 failure)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
```

My project not using plugins that requiere cocoapods. Anyway, my cocoapods is up to date.

```
pod --version
```

1.9.3

my Podfile (inside /platforms/ios)

```
# DO NOT MODIFY -- auto-generated by Apache Cordova

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'myproject' do
    project 'Obra Social Camioneros Santa FeÌ.xcodeproj'

end
```

I tried remove Pod folder and then run in Terminal 'pod install', but when build I still getting that error.

What is wrong?

Comment: Try running this command in the ios/App folder: `pod install --repo-update`

Comment: have you tried --force?

Comment: `pod deintegrate` may help

Answer (score 0):

Fixed removed and then added platform ios.

Thanks for yours answers.